# installing debian with debootstrap and lxc instead of debootstrap and chroot

Tags: debian, chroot, lxc

So I need to 'install' (or rather prepare a root filesystem for) a Debian system and that was done with debootstrap and chroot before. However due to the not-very-existent isolation of chroots (with regards to networking, reboots, etc.), this is a bit annoying.

So I thought about using LXC instead of chroot. Is that possible? Are there any good instructions on how to do that? Keep in mind, that the resulting root filesystem is finally supposed to run on actual hardware, not in an LXC environment.

Comment: What specific problems are you encountering with a standard chroot install?  There's no need to bring up networking within the chroot, though you may configure it.  There's no need to reboot during the chroot installation process until you've got a system that's capable of running free-standing on its own, at which point the chroot host can and should be jetisoned (it's just there as a convenience for the install). What are you trying to accomplish, and what are your constraints?

Answer (score 0):

The problems you will face is that when creating an LXC container you will lack:

- `/boot`
- a kernel

So to be able to make it a usable OS that can run on hardware, you will need to install those things one way or another. When you want to do this, you can resort to chroot temporarily to install a kernel and bootloader.